# Error en operador ternario Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
// Write JavaScript here 
(function() {
    var contador = 0;
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", identificar);

    function identificar() {
        contador === 2 ? play.disabled = true : contador++ 
    }
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="play" type="button" value="Jugar"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

El error está en la `funcion identificar`, pero en la consola de Google me aparece:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Entonces, no sé cuál es el error.

Y segunda cosa, ¿cómo se puede incluir más de una instrucción si sale `true` en el operador ternario?

Comment: `document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", identificar);` El punto para llamar al evento.

Comment: aún asi, no realiza su función.

Comment: Porque tampoco tienes una variable que se llame play

Comment: play es un elemento html

Comment: Entonces te falta poner más código para que tu pregunta tenga un ejemplo mínimo y funcional, porque así como está en JSFiddle manda error porque no detecta ninguna variable llamada play-

Comment: @EduardoSebastian debería añadir el código HTML también para abordar mejor su problema

Comment: @EduardoSebastian en realidad si defines identificar pero no el método identificar() eso puede provocar el mensaje.

Comment: Jorgesys, me podrias formular una mejor explicación? por favor :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes definir el método de esta forma al configurar un listener :

```
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", identificar);
```

Además debes tener un elemento llamado `play` el cual llame el método identificar al dar click.

Ejemplo:

```js
var contador = 0;

function identificar() {
contador === 2 ? play.disabled = true : contador++;
alert("Se ejecuta metodo identificar");
}

document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", identificar);
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="play" type="button" value="Jugar"/>
</body>
</html>
```

---

En cuanto a la operación ternaría, únicamente puedes obtener un valor (`true` o `false`) dependiendo de la expresión definida, pero puedes ejecutar otras instrucciones separandolas por coma y conteniendolas entre parentesis.

> Cómo se puede incluir más de una instrucción si sale true en el
>   operador ternario?

Ejemplo:

```
contador === 2 ? (contador+=19, play.disabled = true, alert("valor true")) : contador++;
```

Comment: me funcionó :), pero... porqué no funciona con la funcion IIFE ?, si me pudieras explicar por favor

Comment: que es tu elemento play ? @EduardoSebastian

Comment: ya he puesto el código html

Comment: A los que votaron negativo: nunca está de más un comentario a modo de retroalimentación para saber qué está mal o qué se puede mejorar.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian gracias por agregar tu código html, edité la  respuesta para que funcione con IIFE.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian gracias por agregar tu código html, edité la respuesta para que funcione mediante IIFE y agrego información sobre la operación ternaria. saludos.

Comment: no entendí la parte de: únicamente puedes obtener dos valores dependiendo de la expresión definida

Comment: gracias jorge :)

Comment: @EduardoSebastian una disculpa he redactado mejor, saludos.